# Математика. Алгоритм вычисления промежуточной точки в трех мерном пространстве

Tags: алгоритм, математика, поиск, геометрия, координаты

Присутствует массив

```
0   0   0
500 0   0
1000    0   0
1500    0   0
2000    0   0
2500    0   0
3000    0   0
3500    0   0
4000    0   0
4500    0   0
5000    0   0
5500    0   0
6000    0   0
6500    0   0
7000    0   0
7500    0   0
0   500 0
500 500 0
1000    500 0
1500    500 0
2000    500 0
2500    500 0
3000    500 0
3500    500 0
4000    500 0
4500    500 0
5000    500 0
5500    500 0
6000    500 0
6500    500 0
7000    500 0
7500    500 0
0   1000    0
500 1000    0
1000    1000    0
1500    1000    0
2000    1000    0
2500    1000    0
................
................
6500    4000    1405
7000    4000    1405
7500    4000    1405
0   4420    1405
500 4420    1405
1000    4420    1405
1500    4420    1405
2000    4420    1405
2500    4420    1405
3000    4420    1405
3500    4420    1405
4000    4420    1405
4500    4420    1405
5000    4420    1405
5500    4420    1405
6000    4420    1405
6500    4420    1405
7000    4420    1405
7500    4420    1405
```

назовём его реальный
в реальности от отличается от него тем, что каждое значение в массиве, отличается на 1-2-3-4 единицы в разные стороны

т.е. этот массив своеобразная трехмерная сетка первая координата Х, вторая У, третья Z

Присутствует программа управления,которая выдает идеальное значение

Необходимо найти два номера трехмерного значения (номера строки) между которыми лежит выдаваемое программой значение.

6 значений Z (шаг 250)
10 значений Y (шаг 500)
16 значений X (шаг 500)

Проблема в том что такое значение (позиция) может лежать в нескольких диапазонах.

например сейчас алгоритм следующий
выдаваемая программой позиция, делит каждое значение на дискрету (т.е. Z/250 X и Y на 500)
и находит соответственно интервал в котором лежит каждое значение.
после каждый интервал округляется, и если он был округлен в большую сторону то второй интервал на единицу меньше, и соответственно если в меньшую округлен то второй интервал в большую.
Ну и дальше, зная интервал сначала находим интервал Z в нем выбираем интервал Y и там берем интервал Х.

по факту я пришел к тому что  для двух координат, таких пар, две.
какую пару необходимо выбрать, как и почему?
пример

X=2780 Y=250
точка лежит между интервалом (2500 0) и (3000 500) и наоборот (2500 500) и (3000 0)
для трех координат картина соответственно немного другая, пока решаю для двух.
Пример:
на первой картинке определяется две точки number1 и number2, при координатах 250 250 мой алгоритм считает что эта позиция находится между позициями под номерами 18 и 1, но если немного изменить, написав 249 и 250, картинка изменится и позиции между которыми она находится так же изменятся[image: Картинка 1]

[image: Картинка 2]

Comment: Непонятно, что в трёхмерном случае означает «между». Вот у вас есть единичный куб, его центр лежит между какими вершинами?

Comment: Да и в двумерном случае та же проблема. «Лежать между» кажется мне существенно одномерным понятием.

Comment: @VladD для начала: на выходе получаются не кубы, а очень разные параллелепипеды. Его центр у куба, так же будет между двумя парами, т.е. двумя разными диагональными вершинами

объясню дальше, в данном случае, если по середине, лежит на двух интервалах, т.е. может находится в данном случае, между двумя разными парами, описано в примере, в конце.
который чуть чуть подправил

Comment: @VladD
у одного диапазона\интервала прямо пропорциональная зависимость, у второго обратно соответственно
первый (2500 0) и (3000 500) 
второй (2500 500) и (3000 0)

Но по факту правильным должен быть один, тем более в случае если точка не на середине, да и тем более по трем координатам

Comment: Если задача состоит в том, что б проверить лежит ли точка на линии - берете *общее уравнение линии* - подставляете туда координаты и получаете ответ.

Comment: Давайте так поставим задачу:
1) даны непересекающиеся прямоугольные параллелепипеды
2) требуется установить, в каком параллелепипеде лежит точка
Такая постановка верна?

Comment: @gbg
задача верна, нужно узнать в каком она лежит, и после найти точные ее координаты (ну эт вроде понятно)

Comment: Тогда следующий вопрос - у вас список параллелепипедов в более явном виде есть? Или только список их углов?

Comment: @gbg только список координат углов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По итогам комментирования, я прихожу к выводу, что вам поможет либо [BSP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0), либо октодерево.

Идея такая:

1) для всех вершин в списке, нужно добавить вершину к текущему разбиению

Под текущим разбиением понимаем список прямоугольных параллелепипедов. Изначально он состоит из п/п со сторонам в бесконечности. При добавлении в него точки вы получите 8 п/п с углом в этой точке и сторонами в бесконечности.

Добавление точки состоит в поиске п/п, внутри которого эта точка лежит (проверкой 6 неравенств) и замене этого п/п на 8 новых, на которые она разбивает исходный.

Поиск п/п, в котором лежит заданная точка - это первый шаг алгоритма разбиения.

Comment: Изначально он состоит из п/п со сторонам в бесконечности

Не совсем, есть трехмерная область пространства размерами 7500 на 4420 на 1405
и она разбита на даже не на кубики, а на точки
в плоскости ХУ  на разных Z
пока, придумали чуть проще чем bsp  и октодерево.
Есть точка в пространстве
Определяем куб в котором она лежит с помощью всего того что  я описывал выше.
Куб находим исходя из того что знаем одну любую точно ориентированную диагональ.
Далее разбиваем псевдокуб, а скорее всего параллелепипед, по половине, запоминаем в какой половине, и так дробим по 3м координатам

Comment: будет ли корректным такой способ?

Comment: Мне ваш алгоритм кажется менее прозрачным, чем мой. Кроме того, в моем алгоритме поиск будет работать за логарифмическое время.